# Vim insert infront of text

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor

Let's say I have a line like this:

```
pick 22086f5 do something....
```

I can put my cursor on the "p" in pick and delete word, however the line then looks like:

```
22086f5 do something....
```

and I can do a replace on 2 and replace it with an "s", but that's not really what I want. What I want is a simple way to insert 1 character without going into insert mode.

Comment: Going into insert mode *is* the way to *insert* a character.

Comment: @romaini the irony was not lost on me as i typed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easiest to just put the cursor on the `p` and do `ces<esc>`.  If you have the letter `s` in a buffer, say in buffer `a`, you could do: `de"aP`.  If you are always replacing the word `pick`, you could also do `dtkrs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vehdrs` to delete all letters without last one and then replace the last one with `s`. Or if space is not needed then `ders` will work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I would also normally use `ces<Esc>`, but sometimes muscle memory prefers two distinct actions. For these cases, a mapping like the following may be helpful:

```
:nnoremap <Space> i$<Esc>r
```